Non scrollable area inside LazyColumn
I have a LazyColumn which contains some items that are themselves scrollable (a mapbox map). Now the default behaviour is that the LazyColumn consumes the scroll completely and the map stays the same. I want to change this so that the parent (LazyColumn) does not scroll when the user interacts with the map. I already looked at the docs for nested scrolling but that seems to not cover my use case.
Interestingly the AndroidView has this behaviour so I cloud wrap the map into that, but I think there should be a better solution. Any ideas are appreciated!

Have you tried userScrollEnabled = false on your LazyColumn?

i do want the LazyColumn to scroll in general, it conists of multiple items, but only for a subset of them i want the column to not scroll, is this understandable?

I was thinking that you can use: if (scrollingMap) false else true or something like that.
